# Saving UIViewController state

Tags: ios, swift

1. I have a MainController with a button
2. Click button will pushViewcontroller to UsersViewController
3. In UsersViewController, I will load an table view of users with an selected cell to be highlighted

Ask: How could I save the state of tableview or state of the ViewController after hitting the back button from navigationcontroller, And the next time when a initiate the UsersViewController again, the table view will be at last state.

Comment: Do you want that your `tableview` restore the data it contains ?

Comment: @MarwenDoukh-MaruänDuch yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while traversing from the page, save the details in a Manager object, and next time, whenever you appear on the page, check whether the details are there in Manager object, if true, show the details from the object itself, otherwise, show them like you do as now.

Comment: I got what you mean, I used UserDefaults for this method. But I also have to save cell IndexPath for it. I want to know if there is a way that I save the state just like you put a cake into a box and the next time you open the box, the cake is already there. And then when I terminate the application, the everything is gone, the ViewController state only there when in-app (not after a quit the app)

Comment: You can preserve your App State. That however works across launches. For what you need, as far as I know, you need to approach the way like you are currently. Do let me know if you get any other way. I'll try to work this out also.

Comment: I tried to save the instance of UsersViewController to UserDefaults but not possible, at last I still get back to the first method. Thanks @The Pedestrian!

Comment: Glad to be of help @VuDinhphong. Thanks for accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to avoid using a pushViewController / Navigation Controller by using a TabBarController for example but that might change the behavior of your app.

Or avoid your UsersViewController being deallocated and just initialize it once.

Comment: how can I initialize the UIViewController only once?